# Flutter The Variable isinit is getting true everytime when the screen switches and it makes run condition everytime

Tags: flutter, dart

isinit variable is getting true everything whenever this widget runs i want to make the function in didChangedependency to run only first time and i have also changed isinit=false at the end.but still it's loading products again whenever i changed my screen and come back to this screen in app. only when Drawer with pushnamed is used to get to another screen.

```
class _ProductsScreenState extends State<ProductsScreen> {
var Isfavorite = false;
var _isinit = true;

@override
void initState() {
// TODO: implement initState
super.initState();
}

@override
 void didChangeDependencies() {
 if (_isinit) {
 print('loading products');
 
  Provider.of<ProductsPov>(context, listen: false).GetandFetchProducts());
  _isinit = false;
 }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Good to know that. Please post then an answer to your own question so it helps other users as well. You can even approve it ✅ as the right one.